# Creating url out of user's choices from the form. Django gives NoReverseMatch, saying i need at least two arguments and i have none

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

So basically i have form on my homepage that asks users to choose two cities : where they are now, and where they want to go. I display all the available options with ModelChoiceField() easily, but when i try to use user's choices to make arguments for url, i get NoReverseMatch. I did a little research and found out due to the fact that at the time when page is loaded, user hasn't chosen anything, so there are no arguments. After that, i took different approach - i tried to set /search/ as url for the form. There, i extracted user's choices and tried to redirect back to the main url with these two arguments. Error still persists

Traceback Url : 
http://dpaste.com/34E3S2V

Here's my forms.py :

```
class RouteForm(forms.Form):
location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all())
destination = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Destination.objects.all())
```

Here's my template :

```
<p> From where to where ? </p>
<form action="{% url 'listings:search' %}" method="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="Let's go!">
</form>
```

My urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('<location>/<destination>', views.route, name="route"),
    path('search/', views.search, name="search")
]
```

and views.py :

```
def index(request):
    form = forms.RouteForm()
    listings = Listing.objects.all()
    context = {"listings" : listings, "form" : form }
def route(request, location, destination):
    current_location = Location.objects.get(city=location)
    future_destination = Destination.objects.get(city=destination)
    context = {"current_location" : current_location, "future_destination" : future_destination}
    return render(request, 'listings/route.html', context)
def search(request, location, destination):
    chosen_location = Location.objects.get(pk=request.POST['location'])
    chosen_destination = Destination.objects.get(pk=request.POST['destination'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listings:route', args=[chosen_location, chosen_destination]))
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show the full traceback in your question. Actually, the code you've shown wouldn't give that error; instead you would get a TypeError for the `search` view.

Nevertheless, you have quite a few things wrong here.

Firstly, you need to decide how you want to represent those fields in the URL. You can't just put a Location object in a URL. Do you want to use numeric IDs, or string slugs? Assuming you want to use slugs, your URL would be:

```
path('<slug:location>/<slug:destination>', views.route, name="route"),
```

Secondly, you shouldn't have location and destination as parameters to the search function. They *aren't* being passed in the URL, but you in the POST data.

Next, you need to actually use the Django form you've defined, and get the values from that form cleaned_data. Using the form - in particular calling its `is_valid()` method - ensures that the user actually chooses options from the fields. So the search function needs to look like this:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RouteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            chosen_location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            chosen_destination = form.cleaned_data['destination']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listings:route', args=[chosen_location.city, chosen_destination.city]))
    else:
        form = RouteForm()
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Added the link, is that more appropriate? Secondly, should i make new 'search.html' template? Isn't it supposed to just accept user's choices, and then return arguments to listings:route? Thirdly, after if form.is_valid(), shouldn't it be search_form.cleaned_data['location'] instead of just form.cleaned_data?

Comment: That traceback shows completely different code to what you have posted - the form action attribute contains `{% url 'listings:route' location.location destination.destination %}`.

Comment: Oh, that must be outdated. i changed those.

Comment: I forgot to save it after editing those parts. i'm such an idiot :D thanks so much for your help.